# is it possible to open and edit a file inside of a zip file using php?

Tags: php, zip, session-cookies, sessionid

I'm working on a WordPress theme which needs abit of configuration to be working properly.

When i say configuration, i mean config.php needs to be edited slightly (setting some variables value).

Now i was wondering if it is possible to be able to go into a zip file, make a complete temporary duplicate (for a specific user. Maybe using session ID's?) AND edit the config.php file in the duplicate to set some variables value. Then close the temporary zip file and echo a link out to the file for the user, ready for download.

The variables value that will be set will be from a form on my site where users will download the theme.

Is this just wishful thinking, or do I have a chance?

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zip+php and then update your question to point out anything that is still unclear to you after doing so. The answer to your question is: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the file, change it, and then re-add it back to the archive (assuming that you have the [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class installed).

```
<?php
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open('yourarchive.zip');
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/', 'config.php');

        // do your edits to the file

        $zip->addFile('config.php');
        $zip->close();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible using the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) class. You open, create, expand and save Zip archives with it.

Answer (score 1):

sure it's possible.

You will however need to write some php code which does what you want.

on the php.net site you can find documentation for the zip functions here http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Im not going to write any code for you, but the steps you need to undego is the following:

```
1. copy zip file to temp area
2. open temp zip file
3. extract file from zip to temp area
4. delete file from temp zip
5. do changes to file in temp area
6. add temp file to zip
7. close zip file
8. stream zip file to client
9. delete temp files.
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the awesome answer. You know where you said copy zip file to temp area... would i be able to rename the copied zip file before it goes into the temp? Because i could end up with a big issue of duplicates. Maybe rename to a number thats been randomly generated. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php